# Memory leaks when using complex data structures (array of array of array of vector)

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, stdvector, stdarray

I have a complex data structure defined as:

```
array<array<array<vector<arc>, 2>, n_ports + 2>, n_times> destinations;
```

where *array* and *vector* are short for `std::array` and `std::vector`, n_ports and n_times are `unsigned int`s and `arc` is a `struct`:

```
struct node { uint port; bool pickup; uint time; };
struct arc { node destination; float cost; };
```

Basically, to a triple (i,j,k) where `0 <= i < n_times`, `0 <= j < n_ports+2`, `0 <= k < 2`, I associate a vector of arcs, whose dimension I cannot know *a priori*.

These vectors are not created sequentially, nor are their elements `push_back`'ed sequentially.

The problem I have is that I find myself with many more arcs than there should be and I suspect that these are *vestiges* of arcs created earlier and then moved (or copied?) somewhere else when a vector had to be resized.

[Here](http://ideone.com/Rg4zca) is the most minimal example of what I'm doing that I managed to create, starting from what I am actually working on, that displays the problem.

Any help is appreciated. Am I using the wrong data structure? Should I clean something up after myself? etc.

Comment: It sounds like there's a bug in your code. I don't see anything wrong with the vectors you're using.

Comment: Have you tried changing everything to use `at()`? You probably have an out of bounds access somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and for the answer that is, indeed, correct. A part from the swapped indices, does it sound like a good idea to use an `<array<array<array<vector<`...? I have the feeling that a simpler, more appropriate structure should be used! :)

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with using it, but I'd recommend dynamically allocating the array, since creating large arrays on the stack is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you got the time and port indices backwards. Your arrays are sized with n_times for the port index and n_ports + 2 for the time index. This is probably leading to an out of bounds array access somewhere.

Remember, `std::array` is a lot nicer than raw arrays, but it still won't do bounds checking unless you use `at()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::array` does not check for index out of bounds, which is why the code is having memory leaks when you have the port and time indices backwards.